# How to give DBA Rights to Domain User Account

Tags: windows, group-policy, database-administration

How can we give rights / permission to domain managed user account, to manage SQL Databases, typically a DBA Rights?

I am on Windows OS.

Answer (score 1):

You could do this using object explorer

1.Connect to the object explorer

2.Navigate down to the server > Security > Logins. Right click and select new login (or add login)

3.In the new window put your domain account (or group) and grant it what ever rights you want it to have.

Alternatively If you want to add a domain login as a sql admins do as follows:

> create a login for the domain account: create login [AD\Sql1] from
>   windows;
>
> add the login to sysadmin group: exec sp_addsrvrolemember 'AD\Sql1',
>   'sysadmin';

Comment: Do I need to do this on Windows Server where domain users are managed? Sorry, I'm new to this, so doesn't know where to do this..